# TypeScript class constructor argument type change based on input

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, generics

I'm trying to create a class which has different argument properties based on a property value. A vastly simplified example:

Let's assume I have a class called `Builder`, and `Builder` will either run a script or build a dockerfile based on the `type` property passed to it's config. Additionally, based on the `type` property, I want other properties in the config to change, so when someone uses the class, the typings update based on which `type` they want. Like so:

```js
type BuilderConfig = {
  id: string;
  type: "docker" | "script";
  dockerfile: string; // I only want this when `type` === "docker"
  script: string; // I only want this when `type` === "script"
}

class Builder {
  constructor(private config: BuilderConfig) {}
}

new Builder({ 
  id: "test", 
  type: "docker", 
  dockerfile: "./Dockerfile",  // `dockerfile` is required but `script` does not appear as an option in intellisense
});

new Builder({ 
  id: "test", 
  type: "script", 
  script: "ls -la",  // `script` is required but `dockerfile` does not appear as an option in intellisense
});
```

Does anyone know how this can be achieved? My assumption would be to make use of generics but ultimately I think I'm struggling to wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) to get the required errors:

```
type BuilderConfig = {
  // Common part
  id: string;
} & ({
  // Script part
  type: "script";
  script: string;
} | {
  // Docker part
  type: "docker"
  dockerfile: string;
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgrgSwDYBMICcDCB7AdgMwQHMoBeKAbwFgAoKKAegahwFtW8owBDdYW+ghQAuKAGdg6BLiIBuWgF8oAMigAKanUbMAygGMpYYF178toSKIBEYgwiNX5W24eCiJUmU6UAfSgO0oABFsPQBrDBM+AIsIaxRQiPQrAITwjEIkOPFJaTlFAEpaWj0kbjExWERUSM16PTwPOD1gbHQ1MCkAN25gaAaCYlF4ZDQsPEIiAsoFRWKaXAgAdyrRjA0oAKFrPokrABpN83BsqzSkg6P6c4zkU4A6BhD09EyIS8CAAxvXu8+oBCVdAQACOiGBKCgACM4MZPi57MB-gkIJVcNhjNwwJBeFBynjcFBsEYEJxpADcH0kEhARBcGIIIUnLRFisRjV2hQrgCRFArLtgJcYidrAiHIcAmK3HykJUALRlD5MKDwuxGf6AqDAsEICHQ2Eqn5vZHYVFQdGY7EQXH47iE4nAUmE8nSKk0hn0xk0BQFWRAA)

You can also mix the discriminated union with an intersection type to  avoid duplicating common properties.

Comment: Thank you! I should have made this clear in my question, but the "base" config has a lot of properties that are required by any `type`. What is the best way to achieve this without having to rewrite every property for each case? For more context, in the actual implementation there are 23 required properties for each case, and there are 4 options for the hypothetical `type` field in my example; would it be a combination of an intersection between the "base" config, and then the discriminated union for each case and it's respective properties?

Comment: @Jack changed to a version that has a common part